# Find all primes $x$ in a Euclidean domain $ Z[i]$ for which $|x|^2 \leq 16$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

> Find all primes $x$ in a Euclidean domain $ Z[i]$ for which $|x|^2 \leq 16$.

Any help or hint is appreciated. From my understanding, is it true that $x$ can only be $2$ and $3$?

Comment: No. For one thing, $2$ is not a Gaussian prime. $1+i$ is, though.

Comment: Is $|x|$ the complex absolute value or the Gaussian norm?

Answer (score 1):

If we write $x=a+ib$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ :
$$|x|^2\leq 16 \iff |x|\leq4 \iff a^2+b^2\leq 4\\\iff (a,b)=(0,\pm2)\text{ or }(a,b)=(\pm2,0)\text{ or }(a,b)=(0,\pm1)\text{ or }(a,b)=(\pm1,0)\text{ or }(a,b)=(\pm1,\pm1)\text{ or }(a,b)=(0,0)\\\iff x=\pm2i\text{ or }x=\pm2\text{ or }x=\pm i\text{ or }x=\pm1\text{ or }x=\pm1\pm i\text{ or }x=0$$
Now you can check which of these possible solutions are prime.